# In what source books do hybrid and base classes appear?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, product-identification, books

Today I stumbled upon this [Hybrid Classes page (d20pfsrd)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes) and since I once bought a few [pathfinder](/questions/tagged/pathfinder) source books in PDF I went to see if I already own the relevant book (I usually play liberally-houseruled versions of 3.5e).

Sadly, the only Pathfinder **rule**-book I own is the Core Rulebook (the others I own are guide-books, bestiaries, and adventures).

**In what source books do hybrid classes appear?**

What about the [base classes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes)?

Are they available as PDF? Print? Both?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- The [hybrid classes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes) (arcanist, bloodrager, brawler, hunter, investigator, shaman, skald, slayer, swashbuckler, and warpriest) appear in the Advanced Class Guide ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/160125671X), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy978v?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Class-Guide)).
- The alchemist, cavalier, inquisitor, oracle, summoner, and witch base classes appear in the Advanced Player's Guide ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601252463), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8fo1?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Players-Guide)), as does the anti-paladin alternate class.
- The magus base class appears in Ultimate Magic ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601252994), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8k8r?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Magic)).
- The gunslinger base class appears in Ultimate Combat ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601253591), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mcz?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Combat)), as do the ninja & samurai alternate classes.
- The vigilante base class appears in Ultimate Intrigue ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601258267), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9j6p?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Intrigue)).
- The shifter base class appears in Ultimate Wilderness ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601259867), [Paizo](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9ujo?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Wilderness)).
- The vampire hunter base class appears in The World of Vampire Hunter D (a stretch goal for the Vampire Hunter D: Message from Mars comic on [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1951067948/vampire-hunter-d-message-from-mars); Paizo is reportedly planning to print & sell more copies of this book, but currently only the copies provided to backers are in existence).
- The [occult classes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes) (kineticist, medium, mesmerist, occultist, psychic, and spiritualist) appear in Occult Adventures ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601257627), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9egu?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Occult-Adventures)).
- The [unchained classes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes) (which are essentially streamlined/re-balanced versions of certain previously-existing classes) appear in Pathfinder Unchained ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601257155), [Paizo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9c25?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Pathfinder-Unchained)).

These books are all available in print from a variety of sources (except the World of Vampire Hunter D book), including Amazon, directly from the publisher (Paizo), your FLGS, and possibly in normal large chain bookstores (though availability there will be pretty hit-or-miss). The PDFs are, to my knowledge, only available directly from Paizo.